# libgdx texture image transparent render

Tags: android, libgdx

I have used texture draw for 2 images, but the background picture becomes black. The source picture is a png and it's transparent. How do i solve this?

How do I render out the original image with transparency?

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
            spriteBatch.begin();
            //background
            seaTexture = new Texture(px);
            Color c = spriteBatch.getColor();
            spriteBatch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, 1f); //set alpha to 1
            spriteBatch.draw(seaTexture, 0, 0, 480, 320);
            //foreground
            c = spriteBatch.getColor();
            spriteBatch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, .3f);//set alpha to 0.3
            spriteBatch.draw(blockTexture, 50, 100, 120, 120);

            spriteBatch.end();
```

Comment: I needed to clear the screen first with this line `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` before `spriteBatch.begin()` to see the alpha effects per [instructions here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites)

Comment: Of course, you need to do this. I just showed the most important part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try `spritebatch.enableBlending()` if you have disabled it before. Should be enabled by default though.